# How to get the mail indicator to always work for Thunderbird?

Tags: 14.04, indicator, thunderbird, indicator-message

I have just set up my email addresses to Thunderbird. I would like to get notifications and make icon blue when I get new mails even if I don't have Thunderbird open.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You may want to start thunderbird on startup,because otherwise it doesn't receive/check messages. Refer here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1529056